# how to escape &amp; from dynamically generated iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am generating iframe and putting this generated iframe code into a textfield so that user can copy and use it.

iframe first created here:

```
<div id="iframecode">
   <iframe src="http://www.page.com/?arg1=A&arg2=B"> </iframe>
</div>
```

i am taking it with jquery like this:

```
var snippet = $('#iframecode').html();
snippet.replace('&','%26');  
$('#wsnippet').val(snippet);
```

and putting here:

```
<textarea id="wsnippet"></textarea>
```

but `snipper` is still:

```
<iframe src="http://www.page.com/?arg1=A&amp;arg2=B"> </iframe>
```

But even if i encode the ampersand, it still ends being `&amp;`. how can I encode this so that user can copy and paste and use it?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: do you need the iframe code from the div, or can you make the iframe code another way and include the iframe src when making it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user *can* copy and paste and use that already. `&amp;` is the correct encoding for an ampersand in an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to grab all the code from the div, and can just get the src and manually create the code for the iframe you could do the following:

```
var src = $('#iframecode iframe').attr('src');
var snippet = "<iframe src=\"" + src + "\"></iframe>";
$('#wsnippet').val(snippet);
```